# Android EditText stealing focus after focus change to other elemnts

Tags: android

I know there are a lot of answers on here keeping the EditTexts from stealing the focus on activity create.  However, I have a bit of a different problem.

I have a scroll view with various edit texts and plain Views whose onclicks pull up various dialogs.  If I click in an EditText and then one of these Views.  After going through a dialog, I return to my main activity with focus on the EditText.

I've tried something similar to:

```
onClick(View v){
  viewClickAction();
  view.setFocusable(true);
  view.requestFocus();
}
```

to force the focus on these views with no positive results.

Any other ideas?